# How to print distinct array elements in java?

Tags: java

here's the code for printing distinct elements from a list of elements in an array(I got this from a website).

```
  package pattern;
  import java.util.*;

  class Pattern{
  public static void main(String[] args){

  int[] num=new int[6];

  //method to enter elements inside 'num' array
  System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
  getEle(num);

  //method to print distinct elements from array
  System.out.println("Printing distinct elements:");
  printDis(num);      
  }

    public static void getEle(int[] num){

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
    {
        num[i]=in.nextInt();
    }        
    }

   public static void printDis(int[] num){       
   for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++){

       int j;
    for ( j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
       if (num[i] == num[j])
           break;
    }

    if (i == j)
      System.out.print(num[i]+" ");
    }
    }           
    }
```

basically i'm not getting 'printDis' function i.e.

```
   public static void printDis(int[] num){

   for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++){

       int j;
    for ( j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
       if (num[i] == num[j])
           break;
    }

    if (i == j)
      System.out.print(num[i]+" ");
    }
    }
```

can someone explain me the loop and what this

```
           if (num[i] == num[j])
           break;
```

and.,

```
      if (i == j)
      System.out.print(num[i]+" ");
```

this code does.

Comment: you might want to start with a `Hello World` tutorial if you don´t understand the second part you are asking about.

Comment: this is your code. how do you not know what it does?
if (num[i] == num[j])
           break; --> if these two ints have the same value, break out the loop.
if (i == j)
      System.out.print(num[i]+" "); --> if these two ints have the same value, print the element with index i

Comment: @KevinEsche i wasn't looking for sarcasm though

Comment: @yogirajput not ment to be sarcastic, you are asking what the most basic stuff java in java is doing. My comment just meant to say, if you don´t know these basic stuff you might want to start with the most basic tutorials for java out there, where the `Hello World` tutorial is actually a startpoint (mostly the first tutorial for java). Progressing from there it shouldn´t need many tutorials to get to the point where your question is answered. I mean i don´t start speaking italien before going through the basics here, just as an example.

Comment: You should consider using a Set instead of a List or an Array. If it is possible, you would eliminate the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
if (num[i] == num[j])
break;
```

breaks out of the `for ( j=0; j<=i; j++)` loop when there are two same elements found in an array.

And this one:

```
  if (i == j)
  System.out.print(num[i]+" ");
```

is printing the matching element of an array.

Basically the whole code is iterating over an array `num[]` inside the other iteration of `num[]`. And when two the same elements are found it's printing the element which appeared twice in this array.